# Unity - Custom aspect ratio in build

Tags: unity

I have made a game that was supposed to be for mobile but now I need to build it for PC. I want the aspect-ratio to be 2:3 but as you can see on the image that doesn't exist. How do I add a custom aspect-ratio for the build?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can programmatically set the aspect ratio.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen.SetResolution.html

Here is some sample code from Unity:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ExampleScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        // Switch to 640 x 480 full-screen
        Screen.SetResolution(640, 480, true);
    }
}
```

If you want to set it via an aspect ratio instead of a resolution, you can do some math:
`Screen.SetResolution(Screen.height * (2.0f / 3.0f), Screen.height, true)`

Here is a generic script that you can run when your application launches.  Attach the script to a GameObject in your starting scene, and change aspect ratio in the inspector.:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class AspectRatioManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Tooltip("Aspect Ratio to use for game.  If Vector2.zero, the default aspect ratio will be used.")]
    [SerializeField]
    private Vector2 aspectRatio = Vector2.zero;

    [Tooltip("Whether or not full screen will be used")]
    [SerializeField]
    private bool fullScreen = false;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if(aspectRatio != Vector2.zero)
        {
            float x = Screen.height * (aspectRatio.x / aspectRatio.y);
            float y = Screen.height;
            Screen.SetResolution(x, y, fullScreen)
        }
    }
}
```

This code assumes you have a "tall" app on a "horizontal" monitor.  Would need to make changes if that were not the case.

[StackOverflow also has a nice answer to this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55204742/1889720)

Comment: Given that 2:3 ratios are not common for PC monitors, you might want to default the third SetResolution argument to false, so you play in windowed mode, unless the player deliberately activates a full-screen option.

Comment: @DMGregory Good call.  Fixed.  I actually want to write a more generic script now - sounds like fun.  One that supports wide screen aspect ratio as well